# Hide text in CSS on all pages except homepage

Tags: css

I'm a beginner at this. I have text and input buttons in a div on a tumblr theme, intending it to show up only on the homepage, but it shows up on all pages at the bottom. Is there a way to hide it for all others, set some sort of parameter, etc?

Comment: link for the website?

Comment: You might think the title is self-explanatory, I don't. Please provide further details like some HTML snippet and the corresponding CSS.

Comment: Not self-explainatory. Add code. But here's my guess: give that div an #id, set `display:none;` on its class and `display:block;` on its id.

Answer (score 1):

You could slice your page content like this:

> There are three types of HTML models :
>
> - Layouts (or Templates, Grids), which represent a structure to hold Components.
> - Components (or Modules) which represent a sufficient and consistent auto part.
> - Contents (or Datas) which represent data could be found into HTML, JSON or MongoDB (database).

e.i.

```
<body class="layout-class">
    <section class="component-class-1"></section>
    <section class="component-class-2"></section>
    <section class="component-class-3">
        <input class="input" />
    </section>
</body>
```

---

So if you have an input like this:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <input class="input" />
    </div>
</body>
```

with this CSS

```
.input {
    display: inline
}
```

you could only hide this on the `homepage layout` like this:

```
<body class="home">
    <div>
        <input class="input" />
    <div>
</body>
```

and

```
.home .input {
    display: none;
}
```

---

or only on the overview component

```
<body>
    <div class="overview">
        <input class="input" />
    <div>
</body>
```

and

```
.overview .input {
    display: none;
}
```

---

or only on overview into homepage, etc.

```
<body>
    <div class="overview">
        <input class="input" />
    <div>
</body>

.homepage .overview .input {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to achieve this. The easiest one is to add at the head section `<style> #id, or .class {display: none}</style>` you use either class or ***id*** or hide the ***div*** that contains them.